# System.Net.HttpWebRequest Does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' . In Grid App(XAML)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Following code worked perfectly in **Console Application** in making request and getting response using HttpWebRequest and WebResponse:

```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

But the same code when written in GridApp(XAML) template, GetResponse() method gave error:

System.Net.HttpWebRequest Does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse' ...

How come? I included HtmlAgilityPack and all using statements. Does WPF/WindowsStoreApp support slightly different version of GetResponse Method? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a Windows Store App (and not WPF) there is no synchronous `GetResponse` method in class WebResponse.

You have to use the asynchronous [`GetResponseAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, e.g. like this:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync()))
{
    ...
}
```

If you take a look at the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page, you'll see that some members are marked with a green icon (a suitcase?). Those are *"Supported in .Net for Windows Store apps"*.

Comment: Your code gave error ... The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.

Comment: That's not an error. It means that the method in which you use the statement must be declared as async. Read more about async [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx).

Comment: This article might also be very helpful to you: [Walkthrough: Accessing the Web by Using Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx).